# Is O(n * 2^n ) the same as O(2^n)?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

Would `O(n * 2^n )` simplify to `O(2^n)` in Big-O notation?

My intuition is that it is not, even though `O(2^n)` is significantly worse than `O(n)`

Comment: Why not try it with actual numbers?  is 2^5 the same as 5 * 2^5?

Comment: 1: O (1 * 2) vs O (1)
2: O (2 * 4) vs O (4)
3: O (3 * 8) vs O (8) 
....
N .... 
It's obsious...

Comment: @MajorProductions Of course, `5 * 2 ^ 5` isn't equal to `2^5`, but `O(5 * 2 ^ 5)` *is* equal to `O(2^5)` (and to O(1)), so it's unclear to me what point you're trying to make.

Comment: The point is that you can still roughly model/visualize what the different functions' curves are by plugging in actual numbers and comparing (as @yazabara shows above)

Comment: They are not the same thing, there is an extra `N` amount of work in the `O(n * 2^n)`.

Answer (score 3):

O(n * 2^n) is not equal to O(2^n) and is much worse than O(2^n).

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct. O(n * 2^n) is not equal to O(2^n) and you can see that by definition of big-O. That is,

[image]

But with some random `k`, with only taking `n=k+1` you demonstrate that the inequality isn’t true.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to elucidate this is to compute the quotient of both quantities and let `n` tend to infinity. In this case the quotient is

```
n*2^n/2^n = n
```

which tends to infinity as `n` goes to infinity. Since the limit is not bounded by any constant, the answer is that `O(n*2^n)` grows much faster than `O(2^n)`